# Azure DevOps Notifications When Added to a Project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, user-permissions

Is there any way to receive an email notification when you are added to a project in Azure DevOps?  I've seen a few different ones around builds and pipelines, etc. but nothing for being added to a project.

We've got a number of projects and people may be added well in advance of a work item being assigned to them (for information more than anything).  Just wondered if there was a quick way of being able to set this so people have less of an excuse to say they've not had sight of something important.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> receive an email notification when you are added to a project

I am afraid that this is currently not possible in azure devops. Azure devops supports sending email notifications when inviting users into the organization, but it does not provide a subscription to add users to the project.

Apart from the negative answer, I think what you want is a good idea! So I post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1218373/azure-devops-notifications-when-added-to-a-project.html) in DC forum, which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.